# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:126968" in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, numberformatexception

So  i am gettting this error while trying to get the images from gallery in my code. So i am getting the images and using sillicompressor library to compress the images and i m getting this error on this compression line

**" File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp" + i)));"**

Code

```
    activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {


            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && null != result.getData()) {

                if (result.getData().getClipData() != null) {
                    int countofImages = result.getData().getClipData().getItemCount();


                        //this part is to select multiple images
                        for (int i = 0; i < countofImages; i++) {

                            if (imageList.size() < 8)
                            {
                                 imageuri = result.getData().getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();

                                File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp" + i)));
                                compresseduri = Uri.fromFile(file);


                                imageList.add(new CustomModel(getfilename(imageuri), compresseduri));
                            } else
                                {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't select more than 8 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        //then notify the adapter
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    rentSell3Binding.totalphotos.setText("Photos (" + imageList.size() + ")");

                    }
                    //this part is to select single image
                    else {
                    if (imageList.size()<8) {
                         imageuri = result.getData().getData();

                        File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp")));

                        compresseduri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                        imageList.add(new CustomModel(getfilename(imageuri), compresseduri));

                    }else
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't select more than 8 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    //notify the adapter
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    rentSell3Binding.totalphotos.setText("Photos (" + imageList.size() + ")");

                    }
            }
```

**Error i am getting**

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:126968" on this line 
     File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp" + i)));"
```

Comment: `So i am gettting this error while trying to get the images from gallery` No. You get an error because you mess around with a nice uri trying to get a path from it. Dont do such nasty things. Just use the uri directly.

Comment: hey thank you for your response so please correct me because i m using the Silli Compressor to compress the images and that's where i am getting errror

Comment: I already corrected you.

Comment: but you are saying to use the uri directly without putting it within the compressor code but i want it to get it once it is compressed

Comment: No you try to use it to compress. Before it is compressed. And please put the error in your post.

Comment: this is the error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:126968"  on this line "" File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp" + i)));""

Comment: @blackapps please check and correct me

Comment: You should put that in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: i have mentioned that there

Comment: On the last line of your post i see. Instead  of on the first line. And where exactly in that line? Why such a complicated line? Split it.  I see no input string. Who is trying to do something with a number?

Comment: i am not doing anything with any number i am just trying to get the uri and then putting that uri in the compress code and then putting that inside the model.
So i am getting crash on the whole line.

Comment: and it is not crashing on the emulator but only on the phone.

Comment: Yes we know. But you call a lot of function in that line. Now find out where it goes wrong. Split the line to find out. Makes life easier.

Comment: i am using thiss same code from last one month it was working fine i dont know why this happened sudden

Comment: You will soon know if you do like i suggested.

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: so i tried but it is not solving

Comment: No it solves nothing but you could then tell where exactly this exception is thrown. By which of the functions you call on that line. And update your code here please so we see how you splitted that line.

Comment: i removed this compression code and then it is working but with this it is not working

Comment: Yes of course. But it brings you not further. Find out which function causes that exception.

Comment: hey i tried every possible way i can but still the problem is same like before